# Reverse-replacing the first letter of each word with the letter of the previous word

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, reverse

I've written a function that takes a message (string) as an input and replaces the first letter of each word with the first letter of the previous word (for the very first word, I take the first letter of the last word):

```py
def changeFirst(message):
    msg_list=list(message)
    j=0
    pre=msg_list[j]
    for i in range(len(msg_list)):
        if msg_list[i]==' ':
            nextpre=msg_list[i+1]
            msg_list[i+1]=pre
            pre=nextpre
    msg_list[0]=pre
    msg_list=''.join(msg_list)
    return msg_list

changeFirst("now you are in love with me")
mow nou yre an iove lith we
```

I want to write a funtion `UnchangeFirst()` which reverses this function, for example it should work like this:

```py
UnchangeFirst("mow nou yre an iove lith we")
now you are in love with me
```

How can I reverse this function?

Comment: Well, did you try to write code for it? What specific difficulty did you encounter? Can you explain how you would solve the problem by hand? What part of that process can't you translate into code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is!

```
def changedAgain(message2):
    msg_list = list(message2)
    j = 0
    first=msg_list[0]
    for i in range(len(msg_list)):
        if msg_list[i]==' ':
            msg_list[j]=msg_list[i+1]
            msg_list[i+1]=msg_list[j]
            j=i+1

    msg_list[j]=first
    return(''.join(msg_list))

message2="mow nou yre an iove lith we"

print(changedAgain(message2))
>>> "now you are in love with me"
```